# How to populate an href with code behind text?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to have a link on a webpage that users can click on a link that will open a Microsoft Outlook window that has the **To**, **Subject**, and **Body** fields pre-populated with information pertinent to the request.

The Subject and Body Fields are covered, but I need to populate the **To** field with data that is generated in my C#.  The easiest way that I know of to do this, would be able to create an asp hiddenField, and populate it with the e-mail addresses that I need separated by semicolons.  The problem is that I don't know how to get the actual text of the field to show up in my href. The code below describes it:

```
<a href="mailto:" + <emailAddressesHiddenFieldText> + "?Subject=subject&Body=body">Email</a>
```

If there is a better way to accomplish this than through an asp hiddenField, please let me know.  I'm new to web design programming, so my knowledge is limited.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a `Hyperlink`-control if you want to access it on serverside anyway?

Comment: Also keep in mind you're extremely limited using mailto since the body,subject, etc. aren't really standard and there are limits on the length of characters you can pass to it, that the browser will pass to the mail client, and the length of the querystring in general.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Can you describe to me where arrogance came across up top?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks! I think this might just be what I need.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I asked that above, because I said please and thank you, and said "my knowledge was limited" on the subject.  You sure make a user feel welcome, when on his first question, you down vote it and say he's arrogant.  I tried to describe my situation in the most complete way possible, and showed that I tried to do research on it and was stumped, and this is what I get?  Come on guys.

Comment: @MelanciaUK This is what I get for trying to shoot down a diversion from the original topic... Even when I said please?  Wow, what a temperamental group stackOverflow is. (yes I realize I'm not winning any friends with this statement either).  I will keep this in mind though.  Thanks.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Ok, we're good man.  Have a good one.

Comment: I've removed the comment anyway. It wasn't constructive. Cheers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Your answer did the trick.  Should you put that into an answer, so I can mark it as such?

Comment: @MelanciaUK I've since edited my question to remove that sentence too.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the [`Hyperlink`-control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx) if i want to access it on serverside.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlinkEmail" Text="Email" runat="server"/>
```

and in codebehind:

```
string href = string.Format("mailto:{0}?Subject={1}&Body={2}"
                             emailAddress, subject, body);
this.hyperlinkEmail.NavigateUrl = href;
```